# Dynamically added input fields aren't being submitted in request.form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, flask, jinja2

I have a form in my `input.html` page and I have a set of input fields that is both programmatically generated by jinja2 and dynamically generated with Javascript. The inputs that are generated by jinja2 all show up in my `request.form` when I hit submit (i.e. into my POST function), but the dynamically created fields (with the `+` button next to a given element) aren't showing up. Which is strange, because if I inspect the page after adding a few new inputs, they... should?

Any ideas?

**HTML**

*(explanation: this iterates through a ~dict and `x` has two text fields called `question` and `tech-key` (ex// "int"). This should print out the question with a 'plus sign' to allow the user to add new input fields dynamically. I include one by default (ex// `name="{{x['tech_key']}}1"` means `name="int1"`. Every new input field that gets added increments (int1, int2, int3, etc...)*

```
      <div class="col-md-9">

        {% for k,v in inps['sheet'].items() %}
          {% for x in v %}
            <div class="{{x['tech_key']}}">
              <b>{{x['question']}}</b>
              <button class="add_form_field" data-key="{{x['tech_key']}}"><b>+</b></button><br>
              <div><input type="text" name="{{x['tech_key']}}1" size="80px"></div>
            </div>
          {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
      </div><br>
```

**JavaScript**

*(explanation: This allows me for each individual named div (ex: the `<div class="int">` above), to add new input fields when I click the + sign next to my product. I have them connected to the original form. They aren't pushing when I hit submit.*

```
// adds new input fields when the + is clicked on a given question
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10;
    var add_button      = $(".add_form_field");
    var x = 1;

    $(add_button).click(function(e){
      use = $(this).attr("data-key")
      var wrapper         =  "."+use
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){
            x++;
                        var field_name = use + x
            $(wrapper).append('<div><br><input type="text" form="input_form" name="'+field_name+'"/ size=80px><a class="'+field_name+'"><button><b>-</b></button></a></div>'); //add input box
        }
        $("."+field_name).click(function(){
            $(this).closest('div').remove(); x--;
        })
          });



});
```

**HTML copied directly from my page when I add two new input fields:**

```
<div class="int">
    <b>Did you conduct any interviews this quarter?</b>
    <button class="add_form_field" data-key="int" data-ol-has-click-handler=""><b>+</b></button>
    <div>
        <br><input type="text" name="int1" size="80px">
    </div>
    <div>
        <br><input type="text" form="input_form" name="int2" size="80px">
            <a class="int2"><button><b>-</b></button></a>
    </div>
    <div>
       <br><input type="text" form="input_form" name="int3" size="80px">
       <a class="int3"><button><b>-</b></button></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `<button>` is not part of a form. You may want to look into `<input type="button">`

Comment: @Gerard Actually default type of `<button>` is `"submit"` and will indeed submit a form. `<button type="button">` will not

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of this code. So that a proper answer can be provided. Thanks.

Comment: One problem you will have is duplicating names. Try adding two...delete very first one...then add another and you have two with same name `int3`

Comment: @charlietfl it actually only gives me int4, int5, int6, and int2 just disappears.

Comment: @alwayshelping I can definitely try!